# Add tab to edit product page in magento 2

Tags: tabs, addition, backend, product, magento2

I'm developing extension for magento 2.0. I can not add add tab to edit product page in back end. I try to use event core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after but I'm not success. Can you help me how to do that.

Thank

Comment: The extension already exists https://www.itoris.com/magento-2-product-tabs.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a new tab in the product admin page you need to add a new 'Block' in view -> adminhtml. The layout has to be named catalog_product_new.xml. This is the content of my file (from my personnal module).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="product_tabs">
    <block class="Okalm\Igram\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab" name="product.test">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Test</argument>
            <argument name="url" xsi:type="url" path="test/moderate/index">
                <param name="_current">1</param>
            </argument>
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">ajax</argument>
            <argument name="group_code" xsi:type="string">advanced</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <action method="addTab">
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product-instagram</argument>
        <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">product.test</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: can you add the code for the Product\Edit\Tab.php file as well ?